# Creating two package inside one package in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

I'm working on Intellij IDEA about java project. However, I see a problem when I want to create new packages.So, my problem is:

```
>Package1
 >Package2 // (there is a problem in here)
  >Package3
```

When I want to create third package, it shows `Package2.Package3`, but my expected look like:

```
>Package1
 >Package2 
  >Package3
```

Is there any way to make that?

Comment: In Project tab (left side) you can find a settings like icon called **Show option menu**.. Inside this menu turn off the **Flatten Packages**!

Comment: click on  button `show option menu` (which is next to hide button  where your code files are shown) and un-select Flatten packages.

Comment: You probably want to un-check "flatten packages". It's located in the project configuration menu (gear symbol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Project tab (left side) you can find a settings like icon called
> Show option menu.. Inside this menu turn off the **Flatten Packages**

You can also uncheck/turn off the **Compact Middle Packages** just below it, that did it for me

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the actual folder structure, you will in fact see that folder `Package2` has a subfolder called `Package3`.  IntelliJ is just displaying things this way as an abbreviation.  If you add something else to `Package2`, e.g. another folder or a file, you should no longer see the entry `Package2.Package3`, but rather you should see the folder structure you expect.